# Mathematica 12 won't load on Ubuntu

Tags: kernel-startup

I have been using Mathematica 12 on Ubuntu 20.04 for a while now, and everything has been fine.

However, now when I try and open it, it freezes on 'Initializing kernels'. I have also tried running 'mathematica' and 'math' and 'WolframKernel' from the terminal, but they all just freeze. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Edit: I have tried installing the most recent version, but I have the same issue, except it gets to 'Initializing internal preferences', and then my laptop starts whirring lots, and eventually freezes.

Comment: I am unsure of what is causing your kernal to hang on initialization, I did submit a bug report for this. Did you update to 12.3?

Comment: @Shelton_swelton Yes, I've updated to 12.3, but it changed from hanging on 'Initialising kernels' to hanging on 'Initializing internal preferences'.

I also made a mistake in my initial post - I'm running Ubuntu 20.04, not 21.04.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! hopefully if its a bug, it can be fixed quickly

Comment: Alright, I've received some guidance @user112495, try the following:-Does a clean start help?
1.Does deleting UserBaseDirectory make a difference?
2.How is Mathematica being activated? Is it connecting to a mathlm server perhaps?
3. Is Mathematica installed on a locally or on a network drive?
4. Does the user have any special code in $UserBaseDirectory/Kernel/init.m ?

Comment: Apologies for formatting errors, but check your authentication for mathematica and the your init.m file.

Comment: @Shelton_swelton I've tried deleting the .Mathematica folder in my home directory, but it didn't change anything. It should be being activated online? On the wolfram website, it says the license code being used is activated. Mathematica is installed locally. There's no special code. When I open the init.m file, all it says is (** User Mathematica initialization file **). How else can I check the authentication? I'm not entirely sure how it's being authenticated. Ican't get to a screen where I'm required to enter a license key/ enter login details to authenticate it online.

Comment: @Shelton_swelton Just to add to this, I have also tried a clean startup (by deleting the four folders), which also didn't work.

Comment: Well I'll pass this on, I'll let you know with updates.

Comment: This also happens to me, Ubuntu 20.04, Mathematica 12.3.1

Comment: @Shelton_swelton were you able to figure it out?

Comment: Hello! I have been following the ticket and developers are still working on it. It's fairly tricky and some above my head! Rest assured its not forgotten about.

Comment: @Shelton_swelton Thank you!

Comment: Thanks a million! Please keep us posted!

Comment: @wklm Wolfram technical support have managed to resolve the issue for me. I'd recently installed Citrix, and said 'yes' to installing app protection when installing it. Uninstalling Citrix and reinstalling it without app protection resolved the issue. If you haven't recently installed Citrix, this probably won't resolve your issue though. Thank you for your help @Shelton_swelton!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wolfram technical support have managed to resolve the issue for me. I'd recently installed Citrix, and said 'yes' to installing app protection when installing it. Uninstalling Citrix and reinstalling it without app protection resolved the issue.